# Why am I unable to get the location from this jsonp response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation, jsonp

I am a newbie to `jQuery` and based on a JSFiddle, I wrote a script to geolocate myself. Here is my script:

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
                $("#ip").html("" + response.ip);
                $("#hostname").html("" + response.hostname);
                $("#city").html("" + response.city);
                $("#region").html("" + response.region);
                $("#country").html("" + response.country);
                $("location").html("" + response.loc);
                $("#organisation").html("" + response.org);
            },"jsonp");
        });
```

All goes well except that I am unable to get the location. [In the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/2/), however, the location can be recovered.

**How do I retrieve the location coordinates ?** :)

Comment: you're missing a `#` on `$("location").html()`

Comment: @fiction Now, I want to shoot myself x(

Comment: it happens to me all the time, don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you missed $("#location") # it's updated in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/256/)

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#location").html("Location Lat Long:"+response.loc);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
```